# Default checked checkboxes not submitted

Tags: html

I have some checkboxes on a web page, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox"<?php echo $checked; ?> name="stuff[]" value="First" />
```

where `$checked` is either an empty string or `checked="checked"` depending on what had been submitted.

I submit the form and (assuming at least some checkboxes with the name `stuff[]` checked), `_POST['stuff']` in PHP is an array of the values for the checked boxes, such as `('first', 'third', 'fourth')`.  HOWEVER, if the checkbox is pre-checked with `checked="checked"`, the value of the box ('first' in the above example) is left out of the list of `stuff` values.  It is left out even if the user unchecks the box and then rechecks it.

I want the submitted value to include all checked items including the pre-checked (and not user-unchecked) ones.  How can I do this?

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing code, I'm going to guess that `checked="checked"` isn't actually what's being output by the PHP code. Instead, you're probably missing a `"` and it's causing the rest of th element's values to be messed with.

Instead, do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="<?php echo $checked; ?>" name="stuff[]" value="First" />
```

Where $checked = `checked` or `null` (without the `"`)

Comment: Doh! (Said while slapping my palm to my forehead and cursing like a drunken sailor at my stupidity.)  You diagnosed it exactly.